# Prevent jump to top on anchor click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to prevent the page jump when clicking on a link.

**CODE UPDATE**

```
$(document).on("click", "#mapbase" , function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    id = window.location.hash.substring(1);
    $('.map_tabs').attr("style", "display:none");
    
    if ( $('.map_tabs#' + id).length ) {
        $('.map_tabs#' + id).attr("style", "display:block");
    } else {
        $('.map_tabs#contact-us').attr("style", "display:block")
        $('.map_tabs#contact-us h2').text(id + ' Projects Coming Soon');
    }
});
```

I've tried adding `e.preventDefault()` but it's not stopping the page jump.

Comment: Where is `e` defined?

Comment: Please include some HTML in a functioning snippet.

Comment: `e` is undefined. Are you not seeing error thrown as a result?

Comment: Please see updated code